# Handle a KeyboardInterrupt in Java

Tags: java, keyboardinterrupt

What is the simplest way to handle a KeyboardInterrupt (Ctrl + C) in Java?

Say i have this code:

```
//Some Code

while(true) {
    try {
        //Loop Something
    } catch (KeyboardInterrupt kb) {
        break;
    }

//Some Code
```

There is a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

You could add a hook before the loop.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() 
{
    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        System.out.println("Shutdown");
    }
});
```

Comment: I'll check about that!